# Writing output of Azure Synapse SQL to Azure blob

Tags: sql, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I have a Azure Synapse SQL workspace. I want it to: (a) read the data from Azure blob storage, (b) run the SQL query, and (c) write the output back to Azure blob.

I got (a) and (b) above working -- it runs the query by reading the data from blob. I am not able to write the output back to blob. I was just wondering how do I change my below SQL query to write to the blob.

```
SELECT * FROM
 OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/testblob/',
 FORMAT = 'CSV')
 WITH
(    
    date1 DATETIME2,
    media varchar(8000),
    callconfig VARCHAR(8000),
    count1 INT
) AS [callconfigTable]
```

It will be great if someone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CETAS functionality:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas

That way you can write back data to blob via TSQL functionality.

Else you always have ADF/synapse pipelines to copy the select query into blob

Comment: Thanks Nandan. For CETAS, I was going through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas#cetas-in-serverless-sql-pool

What should I set "DATA_SOURCE" below? I want to write SQL query output to blob store. Thanks!
``` CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE population_by_year_state
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'aggregated_data/',
    DATA_SOURCE = population_ds,  
    FILE_FORMAT = census_file_format
)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set "DATA_SOURCE" and write SQL query output to blob storage.
**Follow below approach:**

As per [MS_doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analytics-platform-system/polybase-configure-azure-blob-storage?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7),

**I reproduce same in my environment. I got this result.**

First  Create master key on database.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<Provide valid_key';
```

Create  database Scope and credentials.

```
--Azure storage account key.

CREATE  DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureStorageCredential

WITH  IDENTITY = '<storage_account_name>', Secret = 'Access_key';
```

create external data source

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA SOURCE AzureStorage with (
TYPE = HADOOP,
LOCATION ='wasbs://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net',
CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential

);
```

[image]

```
-- CREATE EXTERNAL FORMAT TYPE:
CREATE  EXTERNAL  FILE FORMAT [TextFileFormat] WITH (
FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT
);
GO
```

**Create  external table:**

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE [dbo].[dbotest6]

( [PassengerId] int,
[Survived] int
)
WITH
(
LOCATION='/vam/' ,
DATA_SOURCE = AzureStorage ,
FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat ,
REJECT_TYPE = VALUE ,
REJECT_VALUE = 0
) ;
```

**Note:**

the location should be like this as shown below image:

[image]

[image]

You can directly insert data into an external table by using the **INSERT  INTO** command. The external table is already connected to the storage account.